# Error message when applying function to data frame

Tags: r

My data.frame (movement.data) looks like this:

```
head(movement.data)

  Longitude  Latitude  Sample     X        Y
1  -1.581638 53.81659 1099.99 95.41699 65.88299
2  -1.581642 53.81659 1100.09 95.17410 65.89411
3  -1.581646 53.81659 1100.19 94.93121 65.80516
4  -1.581650 53.81659 1100.30 94.65550 65.74956
5  -1.581650 53.81659 1100.30 94.65550 65.74956
6  -1.581654 53.81659 1100.49 94.41261 65.60501
7  -1.581657 53.81659 1100.59 94.20254 65.59389
8  -1.581660 53.81659 1100.69 93.97934 65.57165
9  -1.581662 53.81659 1100.80 93.88088 65.54941
10 -1.581662 53.81659 1100.80 93.88088 65.54941
11 -1.581661 53.81659 1100.90 93.90714 65.42709
12 -1.581661 53.81659 1101.00 93.89401 65.50493
13 -1.581660 53.81659 1101.19 93.96621 65.69396
14 -1.581658 53.81659 1101.29 94.12376 65.76068



> structure(list(Longitude = c(-1.5816382, -1.5816419, -1.5816456, 
-1.5816498, -1.5816498, -1.5816535, -1.5816567, -1.5816601, -1.5816616, 
-1.5816616, -1.5816612, -1.5816614, -1.5816603, -1.5816579, -1.5816551, 
-1.581652), Latitude = c(53.8165922, 53.8165923, 53.8165915, 
53.816591, 53.816591, 53.8165897, 53.8165896, 53.8165894, 53.8165892, 
53.8165892, 53.8165881, 53.8165888, 53.8165905, 53.8165911, 53.8165925, 
53.8165926), Sample = c(1099.99, 1100.09, 1100.19, 1100.3, 1100.3, 
1100.49, 1100.59, 1100.69, 1100.8, 1100.8, 1100.9, 1101, 1101.19, 
1101.29, 1101.39, 1101.5), X = c(95.4169935430477, 95.1741017603222, 
94.9312120174133, 94.6554984032894, 94.6554984032894, 94.4126097693692, 
94.2025416091894, 93.9793443981241, 93.8808752899916, 93.8808752899916, 
93.9071363032427, 93.8940054603786, 93.9662126575805, 94.1237625957496, 
94.3075692760132, 94.5110727848407), Y = c(65.8829940372709, 
65.8941135300653, 65.8051575885002, 65.7495601253183, 65.7495601253183, 
65.6050067205713, 65.5938872277769, 65.5716482421881, 65.5494092573894, 
65.5494092573894, 65.4270948374411, 65.5049312862118, 65.6939626613463, 
65.7606796173226, 65.9163525148641, 65.9274720076584)), row.names = 11000:11015, class = "data.frame")
```

I want to calculate the angular displacement between X and Y coordinates. I wrote a for loop to iterate through the data.frame (see code below).

```
Angular.Displacement <- vector("numeric", length(movement.data$X))
for (dp in movement.data) {
  i <- 2
  while(i <= length(movement.data$X)) {
      a <- c((movement.data$X[i] - movement.data$X[i - 1]), (movement.data$Y[i] - movement.data$Y[i - 1]))
      b <- c((movement.data$X[i + 1] - movement.data$X[i]), (movement.data$Y[i + 1] - movement.data$Y[i]))
      dot.prod <- a %*% b
      norm.a <- norm(a, type = "2")
      norm.b <- norm(b, type = "2")
      Angular.Displacement[i] = acos((dot.prod) / (norm.a * norm.b)) * (180 / pi)
    i <- i+1
  }
}
```

While this code worked, it is clunky and not very efficient. I converted the loop into a function (`compute_angular_displacement()` - see below) so that I can apply it to my data frame using `mutate()` from the dplyr library.

```
compute_angular_displacement <- function(df) {
    # Calculation coefficients
    a <- c((df$X - lag(df$X)), (df$Y - lag(df$Y)))
    b <- c((lead(df$X) - df$X), (lead(df$Y) - df$Y))
    dot.prod <- a %*% b
    norm_a <- norm(a, type = "2")
    norm_b <- norm(b, type = "2")
    # Calculation for angular displacement
    Angular_Displacement = acos((dot.prod)/(norm_a * norm_b)) * (180/pi)
}
```

However, when I apply the function (see code below) I receive this error code (below code example of mutate):

```
movement.data <- mutate(movement.data, Angular_Displacement = compute_angular_displacement(movement.data))
```

> Error in svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L) : infinite or missing values in 'x'

I manually checked my calculations outside of the function. When I applied the method and calculations to chosen data points from `movement.data` in the shell, they returned the correct answer.

Further investigation found that the error is originating from using the `lag()` and `lead()` functions, when they are called on they produce `NA` values within the `c()` and in turn produces the error when the `norm.a <- norm(a, type = "2")` is run.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

- A potential quick fix would be a combination between my while loop and function but I am unsure of how to successfully achieve this. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you also provide how you apply the function to the data frame? And also the result of `dput(head(movement.data))`. This will give us an easy way to use your dataset.

Comment: @dylanvanw fixed the post with the mutate line and dput info

Comment: When you use `lag()` and `lead()`, you get `NA`s at the start or end of the vector because shifting all the values in the vector frees one slot at the start/end (also, you drop one value at the other end/start of the vector). From the way you calculate angular displacement, this seems inevitable. I guess you could avoid the error by removing the 1st and last elements of `a` and `b` just after creating them.